# NextAuth Update function does not update session without a full page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am building a inventory app using nextjs app router and nextauth. As soon a user logs in, I use router.push("/company") to direct the user to the page where they need to select a company.

/company url fetches the list of companies and lists them..I also want to update the session values with all the company data which then can be used later. But session values are not updating..If I refresh the page then it works though. Not sure what is wrong.

Companies page code

```
export const revalidate = 0;

export default async function CompanyPage() {
  const session = await auth();
  const user_id = session?.user?.user_id;
  const data: Company[] = await FetchCompanies(user_id);

  return (
    <main>
      <div className="flex p-4 justify-end">
        <Signout />
      </div>
      <Suspense fallback={<p>Loading...</p>}>
        <CompanyList data={data} />
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}
```

CompanyList component

```
'use client'
const CompanyList = ({ data }: { data: Company[] }) => {
  const { update } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  // update companies list to session data
  useEffect(() => {
    const companyUpdate = async () => {
      await update({ companies: data });
    };
    companyUpdate();
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <div className="flex ">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Select Company</h1>
          <Link
            href="/company/create"
            className="px-2 py-1 border text-sm border-slate-400 rounded-md ml-2 hover:bg-black hover:text-white cursor-pointer"
          >
            +Create
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="flex">
          <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center p-5 gap-5 ">
            {data.map((company) => {
              return (
                <div
                  key={company.company_id}
                  className="p-3 bg-gray-100 border border-slate-300 rounded-md w-72 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer"
                  onClick={() => {
                    router.push("/app/" + company.company_alias + "/dashboard");
                  }}
                >
                  <div className="text-xl font-bold">
                    {company.company_alias}
                  </div>
                  <div className="text-sm">{company.company_name}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

really not able to figure out why is session not updating here.